# SSH is working but Scp is not on Windows 2008 server

Tags: openssh, windows-server-2008, sftp, scp, winscp

I have to build a logic in our Micronaut application to scp a file from remote windows 2008 server to local (tried with both windows and Mac) Using JSCH api. So OpenSSH has been setup on the windows server and this service is running on the remote server.

Issue what we are facing is that we are able to ssh with the given credentials using putty(windows) and ssh commandline (mac) but when trying the scp/sftp(Using same credentials) from local mac and windows getting below errors:-

**Windows**: I have tried both SFTP and SCP protocol in winscp tool

**Winscp with SCP protocol:**

[image]

**Winscp with SFTP protocol:**

[image]

**Mac:**

While Trying the scp from my local MAC using the command `scp myuser@server-ip:C:/Users/myuser/test.txt .` got the below error:

```
'scp.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

As I am a developer, I don’t have any idea regarding setup of SFTP/SSH on windows 2008 server.Although OpenSsh Service is already running, I am not sure if something still needs to be done.

Please suggest what all thing I can try.

Regards,